# Conditional Rendering in React from localstorage value renders all the time

Tags: reactjs

I want to render buttons only if the isAdmin that i get from the local storage and save in a variable is true, if isAdmin is false, i only want to render the Cancel button.

The Buttons are part of a form

But it shows me all three buttons no matter what.

These are the options i tried:

Version 1

```
       {console.log("Value of is admin:" + isAdmin)}
{isAdmin 
       ?
  
        <div>
          <button className="update-button" id="update_button" onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
          <button className="delete-button" id="delete-button" onClick={handleDelete} >Delete</button>
          <button className="cancel-button" id="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel} >Cancel</button>
        </div>

        : <button className="cancel-button" id="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel} >Cancel</button>
      }
        </form>
      )
```

Version 2

````
{isAdmin && (
  
        <div>
          <button className="update-button" id="update_button" onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
          <button className="delete-button" id="delete-button" onClick={handleDelete} >Delete</button>
        </div>
      )}

      <button className="cancel-button" id="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel} >Cancel</button>
    
        </form>
        ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believe your variable isAdmin isn't a boolean, if so, the condition is just saying, yes it does exist, and renders

try logging

```
typeof(isAdmin)
```

to see

sometimes when you set the variable to localstorage it stringify it, so you need do to JSON.parse(isAdmin)

Comment: aahhh, you beautiful human being..thank you.
It's never a big issue :-D

Comment: try to cast your isAdmin value to a boolean Boolean(isAdmin), so you can assure you do not get any false truthy values

Comment: @OliverThomaschewski if it worked, pleased pin as the right answer for other people who might have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div>
{isAdmin &&
   <>
          <button className="update-button" id="update_button" onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
          <button className="delete-button" id="delete-button" onClick={handleDelete} >Delete</button>
   </>}
  <button className="cancel-button" id="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel} >Cancel</button>
  </div>   
  </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).